# How to play sounds in orbeon

Tags: orbeon

A colleague is trying to prepare a survey with *limesurvey*.
The survey is for the civil protect and among other things asks if the people knows the meaning of the different wailing tones of a siren.
I cite from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_defense_siren):
*A civil defense siren  is a siren used to provide emergency population warning of approaching danger and sometimes to indicate when the danger has passed....
By use of varying tones or on/off patterns of sound, different alert conditions can be signaled*
But he told me that for playing sounds with *limesurvey* a browser must have installed the flash player. This isn't an option for him.
So he asked me, if such a survey would be feasible with orbeon.
The idea is, that the form has several buttons and several dropdowns. 
Clicking a button a sound is played and in a corresponding dropdown one can select the meaning of the sound.
Is it possible to play sounds with orbeon forms?

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that web browsers no longer need Flash Player to play sounds (see [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=audio)).

Now in order to play sounds with Orbeon Forms, you need to create a custom component able to call those APIs and play the sounds. This is doable by following the [documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xbl/) but it involves some programming.

Comment: I tried the two links *custom component* and *documentation*, but both have the same address: `https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xbl/` .
Is this a lapse?

Comment: No, the links point to the same page. I realize this can be confusing. I am removing one of the links.